# Installing MySQL Gem for Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, ruby, macos, rubygems

I know there are a lot of questions like this already, but I'm looking for the **SIMPLEST** way to install the ***MySql gem*** + all the ***dependencies*** that are required for its successful installation on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

`gem install ruby-mysql` hasn't worked, I've gotten many different errors, either with "Not the correct permissions" or "Error in " from not having the dependencies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) installed (if not, click the link and follow those directions), you can do `brew install mysql` and that should get you the right dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I found to be the best thing while digging around amongst the other questions about MySql Gem :)

Comment: No problem. I would have asked you in the comments about that but I didn't have enough reputation

Comment: That's fine, I'll take it as answer :P Im also too low on rep

Answer (score 1):

To fix for a manual gem install:

```
brew install openssl
brew install mysql
gem install mysql2 -- --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
```

To fix for all bundle installs:

```
brew install openssl
brew install mysql
bundle config --global build.mysql2 --with-opt-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
bundle install
```